# Preserve a Transform in an SVG element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a SVG shape (which is quite complex, I have made it simple for the sake of understanding) which I need to transform. My requirement is,

1. When mouseover, The group should be scaled to 2x
2. When mouseout, group should scale back to 1x
3. When dragging the group scale should be preseved

So far, I have managed to do all the parts, except one issue. After I drag the element when I try to mouseover the group it reverts to its original location. I cannot understand why it happens. Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roxr9mww/). Can anyone help me out?

index.html

```
<svg width="400" height="400" style="background-color: red">

    <g id="op" class="operator" transform="translate(0,0)">

        <circle class="head" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" style="fill: yellow"></circle>
        <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="10" style="fill: blue"></circle>
        <circle cx="60" cy="40" r="10" style="fill: blue"></circle>

    </g>

</svg>
```

script.js

```
d3.selectAll('.operator')
        .on('mouseenter', function () {

            console.log('Mouse Enter');
            var c = d3.select(this).select('.head');
            var x = c.attr('cx');
            var y = c.attr('cy');

            var scale = 2;
            var scaleX = -1 * x * (scale - 1);
            var scaleY = -1 * y * (scale - 1);

            d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(' + scaleX + ',' + scaleY + ')' + 'scale(' + scale + ')');

        })
        .on('mouseleave', function () {

            console.log('Mouse Leave');
            var c = d3.select(this).select('.head');
            var x = c.attr('cx');
            var y = c.attr('cy');

            var scale = 1;
            var scaleX = -1 * x * (scale - 1);
            var scaleY = -1 * y * (scale - 1);

            d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(' + scaleX + ',' + scaleY + ')' + 'scale(' + scale + ')');

        })
        .call(d3.behavior.drag()
                .origin(function () {

                    var t = d3.select(this);
                    return {
                        x: d3.transform(t.attr("transform")).translate[0],
                        y: d3.transform(t.attr("transform")).translate[1]
                    };
                })
                .on('drag', function () {

                    var oldScale = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr('transform')).scale;

                    d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.x + ',' + d3.event.y + ')scale(' + oldScale + ')');

                }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PhilAnderson said, you shouldn't be mixing `translate` and `cx/cy`. In fact, the way you are nesting elements, you should only be translating.  Translate your `g` within the SVG and then translate your circles within the `g`.  Correcting that, things get much simpler:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="400" height="400" style="background-color: red">
    <g id="op" class="operator" transform="translate(50,50)">
      <circle class="head" r="20" style="fill: yellow"></circle>
      <circle transform="translate(-10,0)" r="10" style="fill: blue"></circle>
      <circle transform="translate(10,0)" r="10" style="fill: blue"></circle>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <script>
    d3.select('.operator')
      .on('mouseenter', function() {

        console.log('Mouse Enter');
        
        var self = d3.select(this),
            xy = d3.transform(self.attr('transform')).translate,
            scale = 2;
        self.attr('transform', 'translate(' + xy[0] + ',' + xy[1] + ')' + 'scale(' + scale + ')');

      })
      .on('mouseleave', function() {

        console.log('Mouse Leave');
        var self = d3.select(this),
            xy = d3.transform(self.attr('transform')).translate,
            scale = 1;
            
        self.attr('transform', 'translate(' + xy[0] + ',' + xy[1] + ')' + 'scale(' + scale + ')');


      })
      .call(d3.behavior.drag()
        
        .on('drag', function() {
          
          var self = d3.select(this),
              oldScale = d3.transform(self.attr('transform')).scale;
          self.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.x + ',' + d3.event.y + ')scale(' + oldScale + ')');

        }))
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, Kudos for the TIP on translating the child elements. that never came to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're confusing the cx and cy attributes with the translate.

In mouseenter and mouseleave you move the shape according to the values of cx and cy, but in the drag event you simply translate using the x and y values of the event.

One way of fixing this would be to set the cx and cy attributes in your drag event, although tbh it would be better to settle for one approach and stick to it throughout.

Comment: My problem is I want the group to scale from the center of the circle. Could you please be kind enough to share a code sample?

Comment: @Mark's answer solved the issue and explained the problem in depth. upvote for the early clarification. (y)